# Spring Boot Eclipse compiling with latest version but I need it in version 11 - not working

Tags: java, spring

I have to compile a spring boot application with java version 11. At the moment v17 is installed on my machine.

I tried all I could find so far on the internet to set my eclipse IDE to compile with version 11.

In my pom.xml the following is configured.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <site-plugin.version>3.7.1</site-plugin.version>
    <project-info-reports-plugin.version>3.0.0</project-info-reports-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

If I right click my project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Version 11 is selected.
On Java Facets Java with version 11 is selected.

On the target system I always receive the following error when I try to start the app.

> Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher

and

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

What am I missing here?